# Find all disjoint subsets of a set, respecting the element order

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, subset

Lets say I want to implement a solution in Python 2.7.

I have a list of strings, e.g. A = ['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD'].

The desired output would be a set of disjoint subsets of A, e.g A_1, A_2 ... A_N, such that

```
(A_1 U A_2 U ... U A_N) = A,

(A_1 ∩ A_2 ∩ ... ∩ A_N) = Ø,
```

while respecting the order of elements in A (A_1, A_2, ..., A_N can not contain non-adjacent elements in A).

For A, these would be:

A_1, A_2 ... A_N:

- ['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD'],  Ø
- ['AA'],  ['BB', 'CC', 'DD']
- ['AA', 'BB'],  ['CC', 'DD']
- ['AA', 'BB', 'CC'],  ['DD']
- ['AA'],  ['BB'],  ['CC'],  ['DD']
- ['AA', 'BB'],  ['CC'],  ['DD']
- ['AA'],  ['BB', 'CC'],  ['DD']
- ['AA'],  ['BB'],  ['CC', 'DD']

(Hope I haven't omitted any, but I guess you get the idea)

The emphasis is on efficiently - meaning relatively fast and not too memory wasteful. I am aware that the number of combinations may explode for a larger list, but my lists are never going to be bigger than 5 elements.

Answer (score 2):

I have found an answer to a similar problem [here](http://solvedmath.com/questions/generate-partitions-of-a-set-of-words-respecting-order), where the only difference is that I want all the subsets and there they needed only subsets of maximum length of 2.

The solution is equivalent to finding all possible combinations of integers which sum up to n (length of the input list), and then remapping the solution to the word list to find its subsets.

Pseudo code for their problem:

```
push an empty list onto the stack;
while (the stack is not empty) {
  pop the top list off the stack;
  if (the sum of its entries is n)
    add it to the solution set;
  else if (the sum of its entries is less than n)
    add a 1 to a copy of the list and push it onto the stack;
    add a 2 to a copy of the list and push it onto the stack;
  }
}
```

Pseudo code for this problem (extension):

```
push an empty list onto the stack;
while (the stack is not empty) {
  pop the top list off the stack;
  if (the sum of its entries is n)
    add it to the solution set;
  else if (the sum of its entries is less than n)
    for j = 1:n {
      add j to a copy of the list and push it onto the stack;
      }
  }
}
```

My Python implementation:

```
import copy

def generate_subsets(words):

    # get length of word list
    list_len = len(words)

    # initialize stack, subset_lens list
    stack = [[], ]
    subset_lens = []

    while stack:
        current_item = stack.pop(-1)
        if sum(current_item) == list_len:
            subset_lens.append(current_item)
        elif sum(current_item) < list_len:
            for j in range(1, list_len+1):
                new_item = copy.deepcopy(current_item)
                new_item.append(j)
                stack.append(new_item)

    # remap subset lengths to actual word subsets
    subsets = []

    for subset_len in subset_lens:
        subset = []
        starting_index = 0
        for index in subset_len:
            subset.append('_'.join(words[starting_index:starting_index+index]))
            starting_index+= index
        subsets.append(subset)

    return subsets
```

Input:

```
generate_subsets(['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD'])
```

Output:

```
['AA_BB_CC_DD']
['AA_BB_CC', 'DD']
['AA_BB', 'CC_DD']
['AA_BB', 'CC', 'DD']
['AA', 'BB_CC_DD']
['AA', 'BB_CC', 'DD']
['AA', 'BB', 'CC_DD']
['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD']
```

In case someone finds a more efficient solution, I'd be delighted to see it in answers/comments!